# Searching for a match in jsonb array columns

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I need to find a cross check for a match if any of the values from a list I pass is in a jsonb array of values.

For example:

```
my_column jsonb ["123", "456", "789"]

my input list ["456", "012"]
```

There's a match "456" that should be returned. How can I write this query in `POSTGRES` and `JPA`?

Comment: There is an operator in PostgreSQL to do that with regular arrays, but not with json or jsonb.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array  not sure how you'd get that working in JPA though.